# Jackson unrecognized field for class name

Tags: java, json, jackson

Following is how JSON string looks

```
{
    "employee": {
        "id": "c1654935-2602-4a0d-ad0f-ca1d514a8a5d",
        "name": "smith"
        ...
    }
}
```

Now i am using `ObjectMapper#readValue(jsonAsStr,Employee.class)` to convert it to JSON.
My `Employee` class is as follows...

```
@XmlRootElement(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    ...

    public Employee() {
    }

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id= id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    ...
}
```

The exception I am getting is

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: 
Unrecognized field "employee" (class com.abc.Employee), not marked as
ignorable (12 known properties: , "id", "name", ... [truncated]])
```

I am not able to understand why "employee" is considered as a property. Am i wrong in assuming that only class members are considered as properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that a JSON Object `{ }` maps to a Java class, and the properties in the JSON map to the Java properties. The first `{ }` in your JSON (which you are trying to unmarshal to `Employee`), has a property `employee`, which `Employee` class does not have a property for. That's why you are getting the error. If you were to try and unmarshal only the enclosed `{ }`

```
{
  "id": "c1654935-2602-4a0d-ad0f-ca1d514a8a5d",
  "name": "smith"
}
```

it would work as `Employee` has those properties. If you don't have control over the JSON, then you can configure the `ObjectMapper` to unwrap the root value

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

But the you might have another problem. The unwrapping is based on the annotation on the `Employee` class, either `@JsonRootName("employee")` or `@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")`. With the latter though, you need to make sure you have JAXB annotation support. For that, you need to have the [jackson-module-jaxb-annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations), then register the module

```
mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
```

This applies for all your JAXB annotations you're using. Without this module, they won't work.

Answer (score 0):

@peeskillet is right.
I was looking for a long time about how to use jax annotation to deserialize the json returned from server since I was getting UnrecognizedPropertyException as well.

Adding the following code fixed my problem:
`mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());`

Follow below the entire code i used:
`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
List<PojoTO>response = mapper.readValue(result.readEntity(String.class), mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, PojoTO.class));`